# How to linearize a non-convex constraint?

Tags: cplex, opl

I'm an engineering student and new user at CPLEX. When I ran my script, it says that one of my constraints is non convex. I know I should linearize it, but I don't know how.

`x[i][j]` is a binary variable.

`E[i]` is a continuous variable, that depends on `x[i][j]`.

`eev[i]` is an input (energy wasted on route `i`).

`edh[i]` is an input (energy wasted from `i` to `j`).
`emax` is also an input, a constant. Is the initial battery level, its maximum.

This is part of a electric vehicle scheduling formulation and `E[i]` is the energy remained on that vehicle after doing route `i`.

How can I linearize the following constraint so it won't be non-convex:

```
E[j] <= (E[i]-edh[i][j]-eev[j])*x[i][j]+emax*(1-x[i][j])
```

I know how to linearize it if it was like this:

```
E[j] == (E[i]-edh[i][j]-eev[j])*x[i][j]+emax*(1-x[i][j])
```

But that is not what I need for my script.

Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: Just to be sure I understood. The only variables are `x[i][j]` and the other values are the constants or what?

Comment: (Im sorry for the lack of information)

x[i][j] is a binary variable,
E[i] is a continuous variable, that depends on x[i][j].

This is a part of a electric vehicle scheduling formulation and E[i] is the energy remained on that vehicle after doing route i.

Comment: eev[i] is an input (energy wasted on route i)
edh[i] is an input (energy wasted from i to j)

Comment: Ok, `emax` is also a constant?

Comment: yes, emax is also a constant. Is the initial battery level, its maximum

Comment: One thing, I studied operative research last year so it's not so fresh in my mind, but why would the second equation be linear, it seems a quadratic equation to me.

Comment: It is not. But that one i know how to linearize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change

```
E[j] <= (E[i]-edh[i][j]-eev[j])*x[i][j]+emax*(1-x[i][j])
```

into

```
E[j] <= E[i]*x[i][j]-edh[i][j]*x[i][j]-eev[j]*x[i][j]+emax*(1-x[i][j])
```

and in order to cope with E[i]*x[i][j] that is a product between a binary decision variable and another decision variable you could rely on

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=aa9aa3db-4fbc-4209-a767-5b5e54902cbd&ps=25

I provided 3 ways.

One of them is to turn

```
dvar int x in 2..10;
dvar boolean b;

maximize x;
subject to
{
b*x<=7;
}
```

into

```
dvar int x in 2..10;
dvar boolean b;

dvar int bx;

maximize x;
subject to
{
bx<=7;



2*b<=bx;
bx<=10*b;

bx<=x-2*(1-b);
bx>=x-10*(1-b);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

I used your second way (from your previous linked answer) - just because I didn't know that I could do that on CPLEX and i wanted to give it a try - and it worked just fine!

I'll try your third now. As for your first option, my variable E is a float one and I think that is not compatible with CP.

Once again, thank you for your help and time!